# Loop through array to find results from formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column that has text in some cells and formulas in the others. When I'm trying to loop through an array to search for some values in the columns, I can't seem to reference the values as a result of formulas. For example, I'm trying to do conditional statements like `If arr(i, 15) = "String" Then` but `String` is the result of a Vlookup.

printing the entire array gives me the formulas, not the results

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arr As Variant

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
arr = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Formula


For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    
    If Not IsError(arr(i, 15)) Then 'Some of the values are #NA
            Debug.Print arr(i, 15)
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to obtain value from cells formula not result in error, probably array may not suitable in such case, use For loop will achieve your expected input also. In my example, Range("E3) is not printed due to error, you can combine with lastrow for dynamic range:

[image]

[image]

I add version 2 here for using array looping, the outcome skip to print Range("E2") due to error, hope it help :)

```
 Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim textValue As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
arr = ws.Range("D1").CurrentRegion.Value


For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
   textValue = CStr(arr(i, 2))

    If InStr(textValue, "Error") <= 0 Then 'Some of the values are #NA
            Debug.Print textValue
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping but I will still need to paste the array with the formulas back to the worksheet at the end

Comment: I have amended my answer based on your condition, is it what you expected?

Comment: it would work but my table as 10000+ rows so the loop would quite a while

Comment: Ya, no choice although it is slower, unless on the master formula you add iferror function to adjust the outcome when error

Comment: I add 2 version for you for using array, kind a interest to know it do work also

Answer (score 0):

your code has an End If without if
To get the value of the formula, use Evaluate(formula), this line only work if send a formula as parameter, use on error resume next if is possible to sent errors, empty values or not formula values... Good Luck

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim arr As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    arr = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Formula


    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        On Error Resume Next
        If Not IsError(arr(i, 15)) Then 'Some of the values are #
            Debug.Print Evaluate(arr(i, 15))
       'End If
        End If
    Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to search for the result of a formula e.g. "String" is the result of a Vlookup formula. I tried something like  `If Evaluate(arr(i, 15)) = "String" Then` but it gave me an error